# Xamarin android project Change Target Framework from 30 to 31 Java error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have to change my target android version from API 30 to 31 for the play store but I am getting this error message. I see this warning about missing class can that have something to do with it?

Error message

Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1489,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.

Updated from API 29 to 30

[image]

I see that 31 is installed

[image]

Comment: If you switch back to API 30, will the problem still occur?

Comment: Yes if I go back to api 30 I don’t get the build error

Comment: Check the Android Target Framework of `Xamarin.Android.Common`, if it is Mono.Android 12 or not you might have to update some packages to change your Target Framework

Comment: Is that a nugget package I am not seeing it installed ?

Comment: You can try to update all of the installed nugets to the latest version and try again.